# How to upload image and save image path into the server using CK5 inline editor using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, ckeditor5

I am using CK5 inline editor in my form and I need to save the values into database using AJAX php. I have installed CK5 inline editor in to my project folder and it is working for other styles. I need to upload the image to the server and display. I have tried. I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined " error .
below is my  code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 5 – Inline editor</title>
      

<script src="http://localhost/cmm/dev2/ckeditor5-build-inline-31.1.0/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Classic CKEditor5</h2>
    
    <div id="editor">
        <textarea>Inline CKEditor Working Fine</textarea>
    </div>
   
    <script>
        InlineEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ),{
                 toolbar: {
            items: [
                'heading', '|',
                'fontfamily', 'fontsize', '|',
                'alignment', '|',
                'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
                'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline',  '|',
                'link', '|',
                'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|',
                'insertTable', '|',
                'uploadImage', 'blockQuote', '|',
                'undo', 'redo'
            ],
            shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
        },
         
        heading: {
            options: [
                { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
            ]
        }
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
  <script>
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
  height: 300,
  filebrowserUploadUrl: "upload.php"
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>  
How to upload image path to server
```

Comment: Does `InlineEditor` works as in previous tag?

Comment: yes. how to upload image to server? . I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined " error

Comment: So use `InlineEditor.replace`